# ssl.SSLError when using urllib3

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to use the fortiosapi library (with test code), but am getting the following error.  (Python code below)

What do I need to put in my code to account to disable the certificate check?  (This is a test lab)

ERROR

```
alice@ubuntu18:~$ python3 testlogin.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 371, in connect
    ssl_context=context,
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 397, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.101', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /logincheck (Ca         used by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testlogin.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "testlogin.py", line 24, in main
    resp = fgt.login(fgthost, user, passwd)
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fortiosapi/fortiosapi.py", line 176, in login
    data='username=' + urllib.parse.quote(username) + '&secretkey=' + urllib.parse.quote(password) + "&ajax=1", timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/alice/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.101', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /logincheck (Caused          by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:833)'),))
```

This is the Python code that is causing the error.  I simply want to log in and run a check to see that the fortiosapi works.

([Here is where I found the example](https://github.com/fortinet-solutions-cse/fortiosapi-examples/blob/master/testlogin.py))

CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import logging
import pprint

from fortiosapi import FortiOSAPI

formatter = logging.Formatter(
        '%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger('fortiosapi')
hdlr = logging.FileHandler('testfortiosapi.log')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

fgt = FortiOSAPI()


def main():
    # Login to the FGT ip
    fgt.debug('on')
    fgthost = '192.168.0.101'
    user = 'admin'
    passwd = 'password'
    resp = fgt.login(fgthost, user, passwd)
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    resp = fgt.license()
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(resp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

added "verify=False", and it works

`resp = fgt.login(fgthost, user, passwd, verify=False)`